# Generic type to declare a list

Tags: c#, generics

Hi I would like to know if it's possible to do something like this kind of thing.

```
int myInt = 0;
Type myType = myInt.GetType();
List<myType> lst = new List<myType>();
```

I know here the variable `myType` old the Type `int` but I would like to know if it there any way to do something similar to this in a context I wouldn't know the type of `myInt`

This made me ask myself why this isn't valid. I know it's stupid but why it's not valid?

`List<typeof(int)> myList = new List<typeof(int)>();`

So I'm looking to do something among the line up here. Is there any way to archieve something similar to any of those?

Comment: You can use Reflexion to do that. Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method

Comment: You can't really do much with that list, once you've created it.  What variable can you possibly put it in that would allow you to use any of it's methods that relied on the generic arguments?  It's *possible*, but very rarely *useful*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible but you'll have to add some reflection to it.

```
void Main()
{
    int myInt = 0;
    Type myType = myInt.GetType();

    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[]{myType});
    var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType); 
}
```

Comment: Well it's possible, but also rather useless, as `list` is statically typed as `object`. To actually use it, either reflection or `dynamic` would be required.

Comment: I'll definitely agree that the usecases for this are limited but I don't know how the asker's usecase looks.

Comment: Finally i gave up trying to make my thing generic since in the current context I only needed to handle Guid but since this compile and it kind of answer my question.